# Is the expression "sick to hell" too strong?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request, figurative-language

For example, can I use it while I'm talking to a kid or could it sound vulgar?
So when do you exactly use it?

Comment: It would be nice if you included the intended meaning and context in which you'd like to use the expression.

Comment: Are you sure it's not "sick **as** hell"?

Answer (score 4):

There is a turn of phrase similar to "sick to hell" which is used by native speakers: "sick to death." As in:

> I am sick to death of seeing this movie on TV.

The definition of sick here is not "ill" or "unwell," but rather:

> filled with disgust or chagrin
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sick [3c]

The meaning overall is that you have had enough, you're fed up, you're tired of the same thing occurring repeatedly. "To death" is just an intensifier. I have also heard "sick to God" (same meaning).

---

If the meaning of "sick" you want is "unwell," then I don't think the expression "sick to hell" is too vulgar so much as it is too strange. It's not something said by native speakers. "Sick **as** hell" might be used -- either in the meaning of "unwell," or "fed up" as above -- but even in colloquial speech, formations like "really sick" and "super sick" and so on are much more common. You can use one of those when speaking to a child.

Comment: And then there's "sick as all get out", but that might be really hard for someone who doesn't speak US Southern to pull off.

Answer (score 2):

For some people, using **hell** as a descriptor (as opposed to referring to the place) is vulgar. It would probably be best to not say that around kids, unless you know for sure that their parents are okay with it.

An alternative word to use would be **heck**, which is much more acceptable. It's a [euphemism](https://www.google.com/search?q=euphemism%20definition&oq=euphemism%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5391j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and euphemisms for swear words are generally okay around children.

Also, I believe the phrase you're looking for is "sick **as** hell", not "sick **to** hell".